# Transforming data into xts format

Tags: r, xts, forex

I have some data, and the Date column includes the time too. I am trying to get this data into xts format. I have tried below, but I get an error. Can anyone see anything wrong with this code? TIA

```
                Date    Open    High     Low   Close
1    2017.01.30 07:00 1.25735 1.25761 1.25680 1.25698
2    2017.01.30 08:00 1.25697 1.25702 1.25615 1.25619
3    2017.01.30 09:00 1.25618 1.25669 1.25512 1.25533
4    2017.01.30 10:00 1.25536 1.25571 1.25093 1.25105
5    2017.01.30 11:00 1.25104 1.25301 1.25093 1.25262
6    2017.01.30 12:00 1.25260 1.25479 1.25229 1.25361
7    2017.01.30 13:00 1.25362 1.25417 1.25096 1.25177
8    2017.01.30 14:00 1.25177 1.25219 1.24900 1.25071
9    2017.01.30 15:00 1.25070 1.25307 1.24991 1.25238
10   2017.01.30 16:00 1.25238 1.25358 1.25075 1.25159

df = read.table(file = "GBPUSD60.csv", sep="," , header = TRUE)
dates = as.character(df$Date)
df$Date = NULL
Sept17 = xts(df, as.POSIXct(dates, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

Comment: The format is wrong.  It should be `%Y.%m.%d %H:%M`

Comment: Haha! I can't believe I didn't spot that! Thank you :)